# How to convert the python function "any()" to CUDA python compatible code(running on GPU)?

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, numba

I am wondering how to implement the numpy function `any()` on GPU (using Numba python). The [any()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) function takes an array and returns `True` if at least one of the elements of the input evaluates to `True`.

Something like:

```
@vectorize(["boolean(boolean)"], target='cuda')
def AnyFunction(a):
    return any(a)
```

or

```
@vectorize(["boolean(boolean)"], target='cuda')
def AnyFunction(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i]==True:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more difficult aspect (perhaps) of the operation of the `any` function is the reduction aspect.  The testing of each item for true/false is an operation that can readily be done with e.g. `vectorize`, but the combination of many results into a single value (the reduction aspect) cannot (readily); in fact `vectorize` was not designed to solve that sort of problem, at least not directly.

But numba cuda provides some [help](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/reduction.html) for simple reduction problems (like this one) without forcing you to write a custom numba cuda kernel.

Here's one possible method:

```
$ cat t20.py
import numpy
from numba import cuda

@cuda.reduce
def or_reduce(a, b):
    return a or b

A = numpy.ones(1000, dtype=numpy.int32)
B = numpy.zeros(1000, dtype=numpy.int32)
expect = A.any()      # numpy reduction
got = or_reduce(A)   # cuda reduction
print expect
print got
expect = B.any()      # numpy reduction
got = or_reduce(B)   # cuda reduction
print expect
print got
B[100] = 1
expect = B.any()      # numpy reduction
got = or_reduce(B)   # cuda reduction
print expect
print got

$ python t20.py
True
1
False
0
True
1
$
```

A few comments about performance:

1. This probably isn't the fastest way to perform this operation.  But the impression I got from your question is that you are looking for something that is close to ordinary python.
2. Writing a [custom CUDA kernel in numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda-reference/kernel.html) can probably do this job quicker.
3. If you're serious about performance, then it would be recommended to try and combine this operation with other work to be done on the GPU.  In that case, for the most flexibility, a custom kernel will give you more ability to accomplish the task with highest performance.